# How to connect to USB TTY from BeagleBone Black?

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, pyserial, beagleboneblack

I would like to establish serial communication from a Windows PC to the BeagleBone Black. The purpose is to have a Python application on the BeagleBone interact with a terminal running on the PC. I would like to use the same USB cable I use for the SSH connection (from PC to micro-usb on the BB), but instead of SSH, I want to open a serial connection via something like TeraTerm, and have a running python application connect to the TTY, something like /dev/ttyUSB. However, this TTY does not exist.

Note that I'm not trying to do serial debugging, as [this article](https://www.dummies.com/computers/beaglebone/how-to-connect-the-beaglebone-black-via-serial-over-usb/) suggests. I'm also not trying to do this connection over UART. I specifically want to communicate with a python application via a terminal running on the PC. The Python application would use a library like `pyserial`.

Since the TTY is not showing on the BeagleBone, how can I proceed?

Comment: You seem to be unable to use the concise jargon, but you seem to want to use a USB CDC/ACM connection, which is a direct USB connection between the PC (as USB host) and the BeagleBone (as a USB gadget).  Your BB kernel would have to be properly configured to support its USB device controller and provide a CDC/ACM gadget driver.  On the BB side, you would have a **/dev/ttyGS0** terminal device, while on the PC side, you would have a **/dev/ttyACM0** terminal device.

Answer (score 0):

A TTL to USB converter will work. I got an older model that is still produced from some company. Here is one I found easily online at Adafruit: https://www.adafruit.com/product/954.

That will give you TX, RX, GND, and PWR. Please make sure to get a 3.3v type if you are using it for the BBB.

Here is some write up w/ questions/answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40959/how-do-i-connect-to-tty-com-dev-ttyusb0

Sometimes when you use PuTTY w/ Win 10 COM ports, it is necessary to make sure you get the COM port correct. Actually, every time! Click on the connection ICON on the bottom, right of the screen under the "^", click on the Open Devices and Printers, and then go to the BBB on the photo screen. Once you right click and go to Properties, finally click on the Hardware tab to find your COM Port. Then, one can use a COM Port on Win 10 w/ the BBB along w/ PuTTY.

So, w/ PuTTY, you can click the serial connection, type your COM Port (COM6 or whatever), and finally click Open.

...

Comment: So once I wire this up, on the BBB side it will create a `/dev/ttyUSB0` that I can use to communicate with the windows terminal?

Comment: *"A TTY to USB converter will work"* -- There is no such converter.   You seem to be confusing TTL (UART interface) with TTY.

Comment: @sawdust : You are right. I typed TTY. I need to fix this and quickly!

Comment: @timetofly : Hello...just use the COM port w/ PuTTY for serial communication unless you use a custom build/Distro w/ access to uboot.

Comment: @DeFunct perhaps you misunderstood my question: I was asking about how to connect to the terminal *from the BeagleBone*. I know I can use the COM port with PuTTY from PC, but I need to *programmatically* connect to that terminal from the BeagleBone side, too.

Comment: username: debian && password: tmppwd ... I am not sure I understand what you are asking then. I am sorry. Oh...okay. So, you want to connect the usb dongle to the BBB and figure out how to ssh in or serial in on the BBB from the USB, i.e. not Micro?

Comment: Linux (on the BB) allows you, or an application, to connect to any interface, such as UART (via `/dev/ttyO1`). I want a python application to connect to the USB interface, so that I can control two-way communication via USB between the BeagleBone and the Windows PC terminal. I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Okay...use Adafruit_BBIO or a serial application like pyserial you can get from pip3 or python3-serial from the apt manager on the Debian Distro. Also, there are many more like smbus smbus2.

Comment: @DeFunct that's exactly what I'm trying to do! If I plug a USB cable from PC to the micro-USB port, which device driver (or which file in `/dev/`) should I connect to using pyserial?

Comment: I say use a python3 script w/ pyserial.

Comment: If you are looking for python3 scripts for pyserial, there are many online if you look up pyserial tutorials or python3 serial tutorials.

Comment: For pyserial, use the UART2. Try that first. So...here is a tutorial on trying to attach the Micro USB to USB 2.0 b/t the BBB and Dev. Desktop: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html . Use /dev/ttyS2 and make sure your config-pin p9.21 uart && config-pin p9.22 uart are muxed.